# What exactly is a Phoenix "Layout"?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

In the Elixir IRC, `josevalim` [refers to a way to compose templates in Phoenix](http://irc.programmingelixir.com/search/date?date=2014-12-31#1420019758), by defining and then using a layout helper, as such:

```
<%= with_layout Layout, "app..." do %>hello<% end %>
```

I'm very new to Phoenix, but I'm assuming the `with_layout` helper is defined in the view corresponding to the template above, but I can't figure out where/how to define and/or access this `Layout`.  I'm familiar now with "templates" and "views", but can't find much info on Phoenix layouts or layout helpers.

So my question is, what exactly does `Layout` refer to here, and how do Phoenix "layouts" differ from "templates"?

Answer (score 8):

That conversation is very old by Phoenix standards. I don't think it is valid anymore, not even I know what it means. ;)

If you want to render something with a layout, you just need to call in your views:

```
render(YourApp.UserView, "index.html",
       layout: {YourApp.LayoutView, "app.html"})
```

The LayoutView is the one Phoenix generates by default in your apps. You can read more about this in Phoenix docs: http://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.View.html#render/3

Comment: Ah perfect, that answers my question on how to emulate traditional template inheritance, looks like it's totally possible and easy to do.  Don't know how I missed that section on the LayoutView in the docs, think I spent too much time browsing the guide (which is excellent) and not enough in the API docs (also excellent).  Thank you for your help!